# scipy.optimize.least_squares where does the data go?

Tags: python, dataframe, scipy, linear-regression

I'm trying to run a simple, multi-variate regression of the form

```
Y = b_1 * X_1 + b_2 * X_2 + b_3 * X_3 + e
```

with the constraints:

```
sum(beta) = 1
beta >= 0
```

I have my input data as below

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(100,4)), 
          columns=['Historic Rate', 'Overnight', '1M','3M'])

Y = df['Historic Rate']
X = df['Overnight','1M','3M]
```

So i'm looking to use the function scipy.optimize.least_squares like so

```
scipy.optimize.least_squares(fun, bounds=(0,1),X)
```

where X = my independent variable data and with the function defined as

```
Y - B1*X1 - B2*X2 - B3*X3
```

I am unsure where the input data goes to estimate this OLS?

Comment: Did you check out the tutorials? Can you be more precise with what you are struggling with? The constraints do not reflect the scipy-call examples (upper-bound) and `least_squares` can't handle the simplex-constraint (`sum(beta) = 1`). Additionally `least_squares` is just the wrong tool as you are doing linear regression it seems.

Comment: You might want to look at [scipy's minimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html); there you can easily add additional constraints.

Comment: I will take a look at the recommended program @Cleb

Comment: Sascha - I have been reading the examples and the documentation but as of yet, I'm strugging to understand how to structure my data to fit into the function and even where in the function it receives the data!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is beta in your question? Assuming beta should be the vector containing b1,...,b3, it's just a constrained optimization problem that can be easily solved by [scipy's minimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

# Your Data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(100,4)), columns=['Historic Rate', 'Overnight', '1M','3M'])
Y = np.array(df['Historic Rate'])
X = np.array(df[['Overnight','1M','3M']])

# Define the Model
model = lambda b, X: b[0] * X[:,0] + b[1] * X[:,1] + b[2] * X[:,2]

# The objective Function to minimize (least-squares regression)
obj = lambda b, Y, X: np.sum(np.abs(Y-model(b, X))**2)

# Bounds: b[0], b[1], b[2] >= 0
bnds = [(0, None), (0, None), (0, None)]

# Constraint: b[0] + b[1] + b[2] - 1 = 0
cons = [{"type": "eq", "fun": lambda b: b[0]+b[1]+b[2] - 1}]

# Initial guess for b[1], b[2], b[3]:
xinit = np.array([0, 0, 1])

res = minimize(obj, args=(Y, X), x0=xinit, bounds=bnds, constraints=cons)
print(f"b1={res.x[0]}, b2={res.x[1]}, b3={res.x[2]}")
```

Comment: i'll run this, this evening, thank you for your time

Comment: I got some nice results, really appreciate that

Time to put those coefficients to work and finding out the fit

Comment: even though I get results, I do get this warning

C:\ProgramData\OWTools\miniconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\slsqp.py:341: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
  bnderr = bnds[:, 0] > bnds[:, 1]